# Is there way to get flex children to respect min-height while also allowing it grow past height of its container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child-1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 179, 179);
}

#child-2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgb(135, 135, 232);
  z-index: 2;
}

#child-3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgb(208, 219, 125);
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgb(135, 214, 135);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id='child-1'>
    <div class='block'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='child-2'>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='child-3'></div>
</div>
```

The contents of #child-2 spill over into #child-3 . For some reason , setting `min-height: 100%` on #child-2 won't allow it grow past 100% even when its content does . The content of the child elements are dynamic and can sometimes take up less than 100% and sometimes more . If I remove `min-height` then #child-2 correctly contains all of its content without overflow , but then I wouldn't be handling the case when the content takes up less that 100% height .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.container` is a flexbox, you should use flex related properties to restrict their dimensions. Setting its children with `flex: 0 0 100%` might be what you are looking for.

This is equivalent to setting

```css
/* do not take remaining space (irrelevant in this case) */
flex-grow: 0; 

/* do not shrink when there's no enough space */
flex-shrink: 0;

/* suggested size for the main axis of the flexbox (vertical in this case), which is 100% of their parent's height */
flex-basis: 100%;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child-1 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 179, 179);
}

#child-2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: rgb(135, 135, 232);
  z-index: 2;
}

#child-3 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: rgb(208, 219, 125);
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgb(135, 214, 135);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id='child-1'>
    <div class='block'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='child-2'>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
    <div class='block'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='child-3'></div>
</div>
```